# Generics and wildcards in Java

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I have recently taken on a Java course about generics and wildcards. I am not able to grasp the difference between them and, sometimes, even the need to use them.

Two questions, please:

1) An order has a list of products, and we have sheets and clips as products.

```
public class Product {}

public class Sheet extends Product{}

public class Clip extends Product{}

public class Order {
    //isn't this:
    private List<Product> products;

    //same as this:
    private List<? extends Product> products;
}
```

2.1) When using the first (`List<Product>`):

```
public Order() {//Order constructor, trying to create an order of sheets

    this.products = new ArrayList<Sheet>();//compiler asks for cast
}
```

if I try to compile without casting anyway, error says:

> Uncompilable source code - incompatible types:
>   java.util.ArrayList< Sheet > cannot be converted to
>   java.util.List< Product >

then event if I do this:

```
public Order(){
     products = new ArrayList<>();
     products.add(new Sheet()); //again asks for a cast
}
```

try to compile anyways, error says:

> Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: java.util.List.add

2.2) When using the second (`List<? extends Product>`):

public Order() {//Order constructor, trying to create an order of sheets

```
    this.products = new ArrayList<Sheet>();//compiler asks for cast as well
}
```

if I try to compile without casting anyway, error says:

> incompatible types: java.util.ArrayList< Sheet > cannot be converted
>   to java.util.List< ? extends Product >

then event if I do this:

```
public Order(){
     products = new ArrayList<>();
     products.add(new Sheet()); //no suitable method found for add(Sheet), 
                                //method Collection.add(CAP#1) is not applicable
}
```

try to compile anyways, error says:

> Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: java.util.List.add

Answer (score 1):

An `ArrayList<Sheet>` is not a subtype of an `ArrayList<Product>`.

You can't use it everywhere an `ArrayList<Product>` is expected, especially into an `ArrayList<Product>` you can legally add a `Clip`, but you shouldn't do that with an `ArrayList<Sheet>`.

Answer (score 0):

The type of the variable declaration should match the type you pass in actual object type. So:

```
List<Product> list = new ArrayList<Clip>();
```

OR

```
 List<Product> list = new ArrayList<Sheet>();
```

will not compile.

The reason behind this is that you might end up putting a Clip object in a list that was supposed to contain only Sheets and eventually end up treating it like a Sheet.

Developers seem to get confused because it is allowed in case of Arrays.

```
Product[] array = new Sheet[10]; // Compiles fine
```

It's allowed in case of arrays because there's a runtime exception(ArrayStoreException) that prevents you putting a wrong type of object in the array. (Consider you do this for the above array: `array[0] = new Clip();`)

There's not equivalent exception in case of lists because JVM knows the type of Array at run time but not of List because of type erasure.

Also, `private List<Product> products;` is not equivalent to `private List<? extends Product> products` in the sense that you can add any product or subtype of product in `private List<Product> products;` but you can't add anything (except `null`) to `private List<? extends Product> products`. This syntax is mostly used when you want to pass your list to a method that only reads the data from the list. Like below:

```
private void readProduct(List<? extends Product> list){
//read product list
}
```

This method will accept `List<Clip>` and `List<Sheet>` both. But adding anything to it will result in compilation error (except null).

Comment: "But adding anything to it will result in compilation error." You can add literal `null`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Updated the answer. I mentioned that in the earlier part of the answer, forgot to mention it in last line. Thanks.